# No way to resolve conflict - error with Razor MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

When I compile my project I get errors with my razor as per the following:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Icent.RIME.Web, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>
> 1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
>
> 1>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" arbitrarily.
>
> 1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.Razor, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.Razor.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
>
> 1>  Consider app.config remapping of assembly "System.Web.WebPages.Deployment, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" from Version "1.0.0.0" [c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to Version "2.0.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v2.0\Assemblies\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3247: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application configuration file:
>
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly that could not be resolved.  These reference conflicts are listed in the build log when log verbosity is set to detailed.
>
> 1>  Icent.RIME.Web -> C:\Users\mkiriko\Documents\rime_au_webapp\Icentric.RIME.Web\bin\Icentric.RIME.Web.dll
>
> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 10 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

When I look at my views all razor methods such as @Url.Action(..) have error "The name 'url' does not exist in the current context.

My web.config in Views folder looks like the following:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <!--   <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc"/>
        <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI"/> -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

How can I fix this error? My project is old and uses MVC3

Answer (score 0):

As this error shows:

> 1> No way to resolve conflict between "System.Web.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" and
>   "System.Web.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Choosing "System.Web.Razor,
>   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
>   arbitrarily.

it seems you have replaced your DLL or may be have changed your framework down.Just replace the DLL with suggested version of them